# Cron job error in cPanel

Tags: cpanel, cron

I have a VPS server w/ preinstalled cPanel & WHM.

I was trying to create a crob job but I got an error immediately after I clicked the "Add New Cron Job" button.

```
Error

/bin/bash: line 2: 3rdparty: command not found
exec(/usr/bin/crontab) failed:
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction so I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: What is the cron job you are trying to create? Can you give us some specifics on the command itself and any code you may have?

Comment: If you get an answer at https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cron-job-error-in-cpanel.660653/ please update here to share the solution